# Using perfectLib error ''ld: library not found for -lCOpenSSL for architecture x86_64"

Tags: swift, swift3, perfect

Here is some images showing the problem.
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please be more specific. What is your problem? What did you try?

Comment: i got what i want. try

Comment: I have the same problem.

1) git clone https://github.com/PerfectlySoft/PerfectTemplate.git
2) swift package generate-xcodeproj
3) open xcode project in 8.0
4) build
5) This error

What am I missing?

Comment: This is because i use GM version of XCode8

Comment: So perfect is broken with GM XCode8 or is there a way to get past this?

Comment: I am not really sure if there is a way to fix the problem. I am waiting for the new version of XCode8.

Comment: A temporary fix can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39556483/xcode-build-perfect-failure-copenssl-not-found

Answer (score 3):

You need to set the PROJECT Library search to your project directory [Example here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9wZQl.png). Make sure the project is selected, not a framework in the settings (should be the blueprint icon on the top left). Go to build settings, search for "library search", and for that setting, type "$(PROJECT_DIR)" and set it to recursive. It should automatically find your project directory.