# Xcode build Perfect failure -- COpenSSL not found

Tags: swift, xcode, perfect

Xcode: 8.0

Swift toolchain: 3.0 release

Perfect: `.Package(url:"https://github.com/PerfectlySoft/Perfect-HTTPServer.git", majorVersion: 2, minor: 0),`

---

There is fine to run `swift build` in terminal.

But I'm run `swift package generate-xcodeproj` and open project with Xcode, Run it, then get error when build PerfectNet framework.

> ld: library not found for -lCOpenSSL for architecture x86_64

Comment: Official answer: https://gist.github.com/kjessup/b7d1d513e1ea2bec96e2311cfe6c671d#file-gistfile1-txt

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to add the following line to your project's (not target) "Library Search Paths" setting: `"$(PROJECT_DIR)/**"` (including quotes).

Unfortunately, as for now, you need to do that each time you add a depedency and regenerate project as a result.

Comment: This is not solving the probliem for me, Still getting the same issue

Comment: @HitendraHckr are you sure you're setting it project-wide and not just for the main target? Also have you tried clean build after that?

Comment: Yes I have set it project level also tried by cleaning the derived data and cleaning the build cache also, cmd+opt+shift+k

Comment: As of Xcode 8.1, this step should no longer be necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Update to Xcode 8.1, which fixes this particular issue when generating project files.